# .htaccess RewriteCond question

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/includes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

It redirects all pages through index.php with the exception of the includes and images folder. Is this the correct way to use the exceptions? Also is there a way to use the exceptions on just one RewriteCond rule instead of each on a seperate line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is fine for the exceptions, though you could add a ^ inbetween the ! and / to make it says "starts with".  As for combining them, you can do the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(includes|images)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```